# Updating and retrieving keys in Redis

Tags: multithreading, redis, jedis

I am using Redis key-value pair for storing the data. The data against a particular key can change at any point of time, so after every retrieval request I asynchronously update the data stored against the requested key so that the next request can be served with updated data.
I have done quite a bit of testing but still I am wondering if there could be any case where this approach might have some negative consequences?

PS: The data is consolidated from multiple servers.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the value to be stored, you can use [GETSET](http://redis.io/commands/GETSET) (or a [transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) if it is not a simple string type).
If the new value is some manipulation on the value i.e. `f(value)`, you should do it in a [LUA](http://redis.io/commands/eval) script.

Otherwise some other client might read the old value before you update it.